# How do I connect a temperature and heartbeat sensor to an Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, sensors, temperature-sensor, code-review

I have been using a temperature sensor and heartbeat sensor separately and I am trying to code for temperature and heartbeat sensors. How do I get its output on the Arduino IDE's Serial Plotter?

Code of temperature sensor:

```cpp
int val;
int tempPin = 1;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  val = analogRead(tempPin);
  float mv = ( val / 1024.0) * 5000;
  float cel = mv / 10;
  float farh = (cel * 9) / 5 + 32;

  Serial.print("TEMPRATURE = ");
  Serial.print(cel);
  Serial.print("*C");
  Serial.println();
  delay(1000);

  /* uncomment this to get temperature in farenhite
    Serial.print("TEMPRATURE = ");
    Serial.print(farh);
    Serial.print("*F");
    Serial.println();
  */
}
```

Comment: Please show us your entire sketch and tell us which sensors you are using.

Comment: > How do I connect a temperature and heartbeat sensor to an Arduino Uno? Buturlin has the only correct answer here: you will have to read the datasheet for the temperature and heartbeat sensors to know how to work with them. that goes for any other sensors you may attach to your arduino. no exception. any answer not utilizing that piece of information is a wrong answer.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30153)

Comment: Buturlin? Who is he?

Answer (score 1):

If you separate your code into functions you may understand what you want to do better.

In the listing above, you have code that reads the temp and prints the temp.  So creating two functions `ReadTemp()` and `ShowTemp()` will make the code in loop look cleaner and easier to read.  i.e.

```
void loop()
{
    const float cel = ReadTemp();
    DisplayTemp(cel);
    delay(1000);
}

float ReadTemp(void)
{ 
    val = analogRead(tempPin);
    float mv = ( val/1024.0)*5000; 
    float cel = mv/10;
    // float farh = (cel*9)/5 + 32;
    return cel;
}
void ShowTemp(const float& cel)
{
    Serial.print("TEMPRATURE = ");
    Serial.print(cel);
    Serial.print("*C");
    Serial.println();
}
```

In you sketch for the hearbeat monitor you should have some code that reads the heartbeat and some that prints it.  If you create two functions `ReadHB()` and `ShowHB()` you will be able to easily add them to the above loop function.

I've never used the serial plotter, but if you wrap it in a function called `PlotTemp()` and `PlotHB()` then you can slot them in instead of the Show functions.